# Installing heroku client only, and not the other things

Tags: ruby, heroku, rvm

I am using RVM for my Ruby installations.

I recently encountered a problem installing the heroku toolbelt with it installing Ruby 1.9.1 on my actual system, which then rewriting environment variables, and breaking my ruby cli. I had to delete everything, reinstall RVM, reinstall gems, ect ect..

The point is, I wish to be able to use the heroku client, and possibly foreman, but I don't want the toolbelt trying to install git, and ruby 1.9.1 on my system.

I tried to do the gem install version, but it states that the gem is depreciated, and for me to install the toolbelt.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for all thoughtful answers.

Comment: please show the exact commands and outputs of them you try

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the [Heroku CLI on github](https://github.com/heroku/heroku) and download the tarball from the other setup. Extract the Tarball and move the resulting files under `/usr/local/heroku`. Add `/usr/local/heroku/bin` to your `PATH`. Ensure that Heroku gem is removed from any project gem files. Reload your terminal and the Heroku CLI should be working.

You can run `which heroku` from your project directory and you should get `/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku`.

As it is self updating you should only need to do this once.

If you want Foreman just use the Gem version.

Git and Ruby will not be installed using this process.

**Update:** Heroku now have an [install script for a standalone install](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone) of the Heroku Client without Foreman and Git.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the Heroku Toolbelt installer offers a choice between Full Installation and Custom Installation. If you choose Custom, you can select which components you want to install.

[image]